# Do I have enough driveway turn radius?

Tags: driveway

I want to create a new garage where my carport is, but if I build a new garage structure, I have to move it over 4' and won't have enough turn radius, right?  [image: house layout]

Comment: This is quite unclear - the plans show both a carport and a garage, as well as an irrelevant upper floor. Is this the plan for the new, or showing the old, are you trying to have two garages???? Is the driveway entrance at the top?

Comment: Also is going from carport to garage in a single go that important to you?

Comment: The plans are for the existing house that is already built, but I would like to improve it (there's no living room and you enter into a galley kitchen).  My thought was to convert the garage to living space for a living room.  To do this I need 4 off street parking spaces.  My idea was to create a new garage at the carport and install car lifts to make the needed 4 off-street parking spaces.  But if I build a structure where the carport is, it has to be 4' from the property line.

Comment: Yes driveway entrance is at the top, and this is the rear house of a duplex.

Comment: It's hard to say because this is subjective (I won't ever own a 3/4-ton pickup, for example), but I will tell you that you can't start the turn immediately out the door. There will need to be a straight stretch. You can't start turning a vehicle while still inside the building, and we're essentially talking rear-steer here.